# Unable to laod google map in android pie

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm building a mobile app which is using Google map API. The map is working fine with older versions of Android but is not working with latest android version(i.e. Android Pie). I have tried couple ways to resolve it. Below is one of the way provided in Google Android Developers guide.

```
 <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

Unfortunately none of these solutions are working for me. Please help me out to get it resolved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "not working" mean in this context?

Comment: Thanks for the reply :-) its working now I just added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" along with above in manifest file

Comment: Can you please post that as answer and accept it?  That way it will not show as an unanswered question.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, did u also added the SHA and package name in google api console? android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" this does not worked for me. Kindly help

Comment: Along with  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  Add this line  inside application tag in manifest file <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />